# Objective-C – ABMultiValueRef get type (ABAddressBook)

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, abaddressbook

I'm trying to figure out what kind (home, mobile, fax and so on) of phone number but I can't figure out how to do it with the `ABMultiValueRef`. I can get the types by doing:

```
CFStringRef cfLabel = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(multiValueRef, i);

NSString *label = (__bridge NSString*) cfLabel;

NSLog(@"%@", label); // prints i.e "_$!<Mobile>!$_"

CFRelease(cfLabel);
```

So while it prints `_$!<Mobile>!$_` I can do some IF-logic to check if the label equals `_$!<Mobile>!$_` but what about in the future if Apple decides to change the value of the Mobile label? For me it would feel so much better to have a constant I can check against. But I can't find any to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These `CFStringRef` constants are defined in AddressBook framework (ABPerson.h to be precise):

```
kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel
kABPersonPhoneIPhoneLabel
kABPersonPhoneMainLabel
kABPersonPhoneHomeFAXLabel
kABPersonPhoneWorkFAXLabel
kABPersonPhoneOtherFAXLabel
kABPersonPhonePagerLabel
```

In particular, `kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel` has the `_$!<Mobile>!$_` value.

Please refer to [ABPerson reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html) for more info about these and other constants defined by the AddressBook framework.

Comment: How are you able to see what value `kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel` has?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel); in the -applicationDidFinishLaunching: of the app delegate

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Phone Number Property labels: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007210-CH991-SW41